# How Can I Use The Internet Of My Amazon EC2 Instance On My Windows 8

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a nice internet connection but when i was browsing on my Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance using VNC viewer, i became blown away at the speed of it's net.
Is their anyway I can harness the internet of the EC2 instance on my windows.
Be it hosting a web browser (yeah, it's a pretty lame question) on my instance and I can access it like a normal web page but can browse sites using the "Amazon Connection"

Thanks Ahead for nice answers :)

Comment: This question is totally off-topic, see [ask].

Comment: About your solution, you can indeed run a browser in VNC (or other, maybe better protocols, see NoMachine or TeamViewer) on the instance and connect to it from your computer, but there is no "hosted web browser" that will do what you want (there are - they're called [proxies](https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy)) but they won't help because they will still transfer the entire web page through your (slow) connection, so you won't see any difference.

Comment: View your own PC through a VNC connection and it will seem equally fast. ;)